# Dynamic gradle command for Exec task fails

Tags: java, gradle, aws-lambda

I am trying to publish Lambda zip file to s3- `s3://my-aws-lambda/<projectName>/[release|SNAPSHOT]/`. The task defined below, `publishToS3` fails with the message

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/me/my-lambda/build/distributions
```

when I run

```
./gradlew clean build -x test -x release
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

task publishToS3(type: Exec, dependsOn: buildZip) {
    onlyIf { file("${project.buildDir}/distributions").exist() }

    def artifacts = new FileNameByRegexFinder().getFileNames("${project.buildDir}/distributions", /.*\.zip/)
    assert artifacts.size() == 1

    def isSnapShot = artifacts[0].endsWith('-SNAPSHOT.zip')

    def releaseCmd = ("aws s3 cp " +
            "${artifacts[0]} " +
            "s3://my-aws-lambdas/${project.name}/${isSnapShot ? 'SNAPSHOT' : 'release'}/ ").trim().tokenize(' ') as List

    workingDir "${project.buildDir}/distributions"

    commandLine releaseCmd
}

build.dependsOn buildZip
```

Comment: have you tried printing the `releaseCmd` string? what's the output?

Comment: The error is happening at `def artifacts = new FileNameByRegexFinder().getFileNames("${project.buildDir}/distributions", /.*\.zip/)`, so that value cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on UNIX environment, you can use the `find` command to search the files and use it's output.

```
task scanFiles() {
    def a= "find ${project.buildDir} -name *.zip".execute().text
    String[] files=a.split('\n')
    if(files.length == 1){
        println("We'v got a file :"+a)
    }
    else if(files.length ==0){
        println("We've not no files ")
    }
    else{
        println("We've got multiple files\n"+a)
    }
}
```